# About free fall

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, acceleration, orbital-motion, centripetal-force

If a satellite orbits the earth  is in free fall, it must have an acceleration because of gravity. Then why does the satellite's speed remain constant instead of increasing continuously?

Comment: You're not aware that an object with *uniform* (constant speed) circular motion has a constant centripetal (center seeking) acceleration?

Comment: Alfred is right. Whenever there's a force, there's always a change in velocity. It doesn't have to be a magnitude change, it can be a direction change as well.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri mmmm, yes, that's true. So this acceleration always change direction and that's why there is no velocity change...correct?

Comment: @Pedro There is a change in the velocity vector, but in this case the change concerns the direction of that vector and not its magnitude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They don't! They have constant speed. Velocity is a vector comprising of both speed and direction. In the case of circular motion, the acceleration of gravity changes only the direction of the vector.

Comment: Thanks @mmainville, and why don't change it's magnitude?

Comment: @Pedro Because the acceleration of gravity is perpendicular to the velocity ector in 'uniform' circular motion. The magnitude of the velocity vector would change if the acceleration has a component parallel to it.

Comment: @Pedro Well in general it could change magnitude but then it would be an elliptical orbit not circular. For a circular orbit V^2=aR and R is constant by definition of a circle and a is acceleration due to gravity which is also going to be constant when R is constant. Thus, V must also be constant as a definition of circular motion.

Answer (score 1):

The kinetic energy of a body is $\frac{1}{2}m|\vec{v}|^2$, where $|\vec{v}|$ is the magnitude of the velocity.  Thus if the magnitude of the velocity changes, we see that there will be a corresponding change in energy.  The change in energy per unit time due to the application of a force, is given by  $\frac{dE}{dt}=\vec{F}\cdot \vec{v}$.  Now let's use these two facts to show that in circular motion, the magnitude of the velocity isn't changed.

Circular motion is defined by having the velocity vector perpendicular to the radius vector.  That is we can say $\vec{v}\cdot\vec{r}=rv(\hat{v}\cdot\hat{r})=0$.  In the case of gravity, the the force is a central force, which means it will always be of the form $\vec{F} = F\hat{r}$.  Then if we look at the equation giving us the change in energy, we get
$$\frac{dE}{dt} =\vec{F}\cdot \vec{v} =  Fv (\hat{r} \cdot \hat{v}) = 0$$
where I have used the fact the velocity is perpendicular to the radius vector to show it must be equal to zero.  Hence if the energy isn't changing in time, we use what we stated in the first paragraph, to show that the magnitude of the velocity is also not changing.  However the direction can and will change!

This is a general result.  If the force is applied perpendicular to the velocity, it does no work, and hence cannot change the speed of the particle.  A similar example arises in electromagnetism, where the magnetic force is always perpendicular to the velocity of a charged particle ($\vec{F} = \vec{v}\times \vec{B}$), and so it does on work on the particle, and can't change its speed.

Answer (score 0):

Think about it like this. 
After every small time dt. The body gains a velocity of a*dt where a is the acceleration. In the case of circular orbit. This gain in velocity plus the previous velocity is its new velocity after a time dt. 
So in essence. The reason circular motion happens or the reason the velocity vector keeps changing is the accelation towards the center. Only the magnitude of velocity remains constant not velocity as a whole. That's why when the force stops it moves tangentially. a becomes zero and not even velocity doesn't change.